# rsync freezes in macos ventura

Tags: ssh, rsync, macos

I often `ssh` to a server or directly `rsync` some folder there to my local machine without any special config. After upgrading to MacOS Ventura, they no longer work. `rsync` just freezes after asking my password (asking password here is expected). With [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1368561), I managed to make `ssh` work but not for `rsync`. Any remedy?

### Edit:

I'm using the base system's `rsync` (release 2.6.9) and it works on my local machine.
The commands not working are like the following.

```
rsync someone@server:~/single_file ./
rsync -zavh someone@server:~/folder/ ./local_folder
```

`Ctrl+T` gives something like `load: 1.86  cmd: xauth 50366 waiting 0.00u 0.00s`.

Comment: Does this occur for any transfer with `rsync` from that server (even a single file)? Are you able to use `rsync` to transfer files from other servers, and locally? What does the command look like? Are you using the base system's `rsync` (`/usr/bin/rsync`, release 2.6.9) or an `rsync` installed with e.g. Homebrew (currently on release 3.2.7)?  When it freezes, what does pressing `Ctrl+T` display?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you. Updated.

Comment: The output from `Ctrl+T` indicates that there might be a pop-up dialog waiting for you to click it (or enter a admin user's password, or some such thing). Can you see one? If you are using a terminal in full-screen mode, un-zoom it so that it's no longer blocking the dialog window.

Comment: @Kusalananda Couldn't find any pop-up dialog...

Comment: Are you the admin on your macOS system?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having all sorts of issues with SSH related tools since upgrading to Ventura.

Adding the following lines to my `~/.ssh/config` file resolved initial connection issues, which might help you.

```
Host *
   IPQoS 0x00
```

Comment: There is nothing that suggests that this is in any way connected to the issue that the user in the question has.  As a macOS Ventura user myself, I can't say that I have experienced any issues relating to SSH.  Note that when the OP is experiencing their issues, the status output from `Ctrl+T` indicates that there is an `xauth` process waiting for input.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can also do IPQoS=throughput. Without it, many SSH related functions will silently hang and timeout on Mac.